# creat an enumeration that containt Integer variables

Tags: java, spring, enums

I want to create an enumeration that containt Integer variables , the result is needed to be something like this :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum Test {

    1("Test1"),
    2("Test2");
    private final String value;
}
```

Comment: You forget to describe the problem.

Comment: Names in Java **can't** start with a **digit**.

Comment: im trying to commicate with an API , where im supos to  send a request and it returns a reponse , and i have a problem with an enum where im supose to 1 , 2 , 3 , it gives me this error [ XML validation exception for element 'customerType': cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'PARTICULIER' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[1, 2, 3]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
XML validation exception for element 'customerType': cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'PARTICULIER' of element 'customerType' is not valid. ] , and in my customer typeEnumeration i have somthing like this SOCIETE(1)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such thing like this in Java.
If you **really** need enum for that, you can do it in reverse:

```
 public enum TestEnum {

    TEST_1(1),
    TEST_2(2);

    private final int value;

    TestEnum(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```